# Does there exist strictly increasing functions which satisfy $f'(x) = f(f(x))$ for all $x$?

Tags: functions, derivatives

Suppose $f$ is from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, can there exist strictly increasing function which satisfies $f'(x) = f(f(x))$ for all $x$? Intuitively I think it should be no, I tried to get an idea of proving it by contradiction any hints/ideas one may provide?

Comment: Is it required that $f$ be surjective?  Sometimes saying a function is $\Bbb {R \to R}$ implies that, sometimes not.  If it does, I would think about points where $f(x) \lt 0$

Comment: Not necessary Sir just given strictly increasing. And also i thought of f(x) <0 , or maybe a function which by a bit manipulation gives a form(by differentiation and stuff) which shows there will exist many points where that condition fails

Comment: Check out [This Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cXpFDlIIczg).

Comment: That from intial onward assumes a function form and we are talking in real domains and proving it not guessing the function Sir